# Reinforcement Learning and Introduction - Chapter 3 - Continuing vs Episodic Tasks

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The exercise 3.5 in the book "Reinforcement Learning - an introduciton" asks for a modified version of eq (3.3) for the episodic tasks.
The Equation (3.3) states that, considering all $s'$ and $r$ on a given time, $\sum_{s',r} p(s', r| s, a)=1 $
   I fail to see how this rule is changed in the case of episodic tasks. Shouldn't the same apply for continuous and episodic tasks ?

Comment: I suggest copy the critical equation 3.3 to the question, to make the question self contained. That will mean people reading the question don't need to download and read the book to understand what you are saying. You can use LaTex for equations e.g `$\sum_{s',r} p(s', r| s, a)$` becomes $\sum_{s',r} p(s', r| s, a)$  - use [edit] to alter the question

Comment: I am absolutely no expert and am just working through the book myself. I think it changes in the sense that there is a possibility for a terminal state. I am not sure how to formalize that.